# Pig from tuple to array

Tags: mongodb, apache-pig

I have this tuple: (ES, (AB, CD))
and I would like to use FLATTEN to unest it and create the following: (ES, [AB,CD]), because I want to store the second element as an array into mongo later on. Which schema should I define in FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(m) AS [schema] ?

Answer (score 0):

Pig doesn't have any built-in function or schema to convert tuple to array. Not sure this hacky solution will help you but you can give a try.

**input.txt**

```
ES      (AB,CD)
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (f1:chararray,tuple:(f2:chararray,f3:chararray));
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,CONCAT('[',$1.f2),CONCAT($1.f3,']');
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(ES,[AB,CD])
```